# How to load custom TrueTypeFonts in Slick2D

Tags: java, fonts, slick2d

People are having a lot of problems loading custom fonts into Slick2D to draw strings with the graphics tool, so here is how I did it.

Comment: It is not a question at all; poster just puts up a HOWTO do something.

Comment: Since there wasn't anything around teaching people how to do it, I choose to answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

1. First go in your class where you want to use the font.
2. Declare these variables under the part where your class starts, like so:

   ```
   public class Easy extends BasicGameState{

   //Fonts
   java.awt.Font UIFont1;
   org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont uniFont;
   ```

   Since TrueTypeFont loading has many problems, we can use UnicodeFont to load the .ttf fonts(it's exactly the same thing).
3. Place this in your `init{ ... }` and replace the properties to your liking:

   ```
   try{
           UIFont1 = java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
           org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/fonts/yourFontFile.ttf"));
           UIFont1 = UIFont1.deriveFont(java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 16.f); //You can change "PLAIN" to "BOLD" or "ITALIC"... and 16.f is the size of your font

           uniFont = new org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont(UIFont1);
           uniFont.addAsciiGlyphs();
           uniFont.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.white)); //You can change your color here, but you can also change it in the render{ ... }
           uniFont.addAsciiGlyphs();
           uniFont.loadGlyphs();
           }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
   ```
4. Finally, in your `render{ ... }`, place this in it`uniFont.drawString(x, y, "What you want to write here", Color.ChooseYourColorHere)`

You can of course change the default names I put for the variables.
Keep in mind that I am not the author of all this, I just want to clearly show you how to do it since all the sources I have used either haven't finished, or were just suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, albeit this was not a proper question, it helped a lot.